# Calling a method in specific interval

Tags: c#, observable, system.reactive

I need to run a method in a specific interval. How can I achieve it through c#

I wrote a code but it is not repeating. It is executing only one time.
can anyone explain to me what is observable and cancellation token. how to use it

```
IObservable<long> observable = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource source = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource();
observable.Subscribe(x =>
{
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task task = sampleMethod();
    task.Start();
}, source.Token);
```

Comment: One clarification: are you looking for the simplest way to call a method in repeating intervals and you accidentally found this `IObservable` example, or you actually want to use `IObservable`?

Comment: If you're running something on a schedule, I'd be tempted to let the OS run the task using it's native tools (e.g. Task Scheduler for Windows).

Comment: can u explain me when to use `IObservable `, If any better solution is there @Groo

Comment: @Iceberg - For this kinds of thing using `IObservable<>` is ideal. It can be a super clean way to code.

Comment: @Enigmativity How is `IObsevable<>` will work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that in multiple ways. One of the easiest one would be something like this:

```
public async Task RunScheduleJob(CancellationToken token)
{
  while(!token.IsCancellationRequest)
  {
    YourMethod();
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromHours(1), token)
  }
}
```

PS. For such a simple job you don't need to use Reactive Extensions or any other external library. You can achieve it by just playing around with `Task` instances

Comment: can u explain me when to use `observable`

Comment: @ijas you don't need to use it. Don't overcomplicate

Comment: @olegl thanks for the help, why is that `CancellationToken` as parameter to async Task, I don't know what is cancellationtoken

Comment: CancellationToken is important in order to gracefully stop all calls and I/O operations. It's a really good practice to always pass it

Comment: This is a terrible solution. It can't be cancelled. The `while (true)` itself should `break` if the `CancellationToken` token says it should stop.

Comment: @Enigmativity updated, sorry didn’t really pay enough attention to cancellation token since question wasn’t about it

Answer (score 1):

Rx is an awesome way to handle this situation. It is super clean.

The most basic rewrite of your code in your question is this:

```
IObservable<Unit> observable =
    from i in Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromHours(1))
    from t in Observable.FromAsync(() => sampleMethod())
    select t;

IDisposable subscription = observable.Subscribe();
```

There's no need for a cancellation token as you simply need to call `subscription.Dispose()` to stop this subscription.

However, if your `sampleMethod()` call was long-running then calling `subscription.Dispose()` would stop the observable, but the task would run to completion. If you specifically wanted to stop the task too then the call to the task would need to take a cancellation token and use it to stop itself.

Yor calling code would then be this:

```
IObservable<Unit> observable =
    from i in Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromHours(1))
    from t in Observable.FromAsync(ct => sampleMethod(ct))
    select t;
```

The only difference is that the `FromAsync` call passes a `CancellationToken` to the `sampleMethod` call that will be cancelled when you call `subscription.Dispose()`.

Comment: can u explain me how this work and what is the advantage of using Observable than while loop with delay task

Comment: @Iceberg - Observables are far more powerful than using a `while` loop with a `await Task.Delay`. You can do all sorts of joins, filters, projections, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromHours(1)).SelectMany(_ => sampleMethod()).Subscribe()`. Ignoring for the moment cancellation behavior (which is easy to add), you just take the `Interval` and rightly map it to an async routine represented as `Task` (internally treated as `IObservable<>`, btw there is `.ToObservable()` extension method to convert `Task`). Note that `SelectMany(...)` is fatefully important here: otherwise the Rx framework won't await for `Task` completion, won't capture possible exceptions and won't preserve the original order of events.

`CancellationToken` is used to unsubscribe from the `Observable` you made up. It is analogous to the `IDisposable` in that sense that both serve for the same goal: to stop and cleanup your subscription. Thus, once you call `Cancel()` on it, you won't get any update.

P.S. Are you sure that `FromHours(1)` is right? You may want less longer interval, for example `FromMinutre(1)`.

Comment: don't Understand, why this method is not repeating periodically. i tried it with FromMinutre(1) but task is not repeating @Sereja Bogolubov

Comment: I disagree with the other answers. While Rx is an external library, it is the better concept for recurring asynchronous operations. It is not an overcomplication, it is a simplification and should be preferred over Task! Even for this small use case

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. It would need to be `.SelectMany(_ => Observable.FromAsync(() => sampleMethod()))`.

Comment: @Enigmativity which Rx version are you using?

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov - I'm Nugetting it in and getting version 4.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

No need for Rx if you just need a timer functionality. You can just go with a `Timer` from `System.Threading`:

```
    var timer = new Timer(_ =>
    {
        // repeating code goes here
        // the argument is an optional state that you can pass into the constructor
    });
    timer.Change( dueTime: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), period: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1));
    // run your app
    timer.Dispose();
```

The advantage of the Timer is that it allows you to reconfigure it anytime (if you want to Change the period, just call `Change` again), temporarily disable it and cleanly remove it (calling Dispose).